# How to get a query parameter inside API route.js using new App routing approach?

Tags: typescript, next.js

Here is what I want to achieve:

1. Use Next.js with [App router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app).
2. Create a back end route `/api/prompt?search=[search_text]`
3. Read this search query parameter in my `route.ts` file.
4. Based on that search parameter return something to the front-end component.

All is good except point #3.

When I run application locally using `npm run dev` then application is running fine. Although, when I do `npm run build` then the strange error appears:

> Getting posts error DynamicServerError: Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used `nextUrl.searchParams`. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error

I've read the article in the error text but I don't understand how that could be applied to my code. I may not understand how Next.js works. Although, I want to clarify whether that's something in my code or this is something related to Next.js bug.

The expected behaviour would be to either fail during `npm run dev` to be consistent in errors during both stages or not to fail during `npm run build`.

[Here](https://github.com/volodymyr-matselyukh/promptopia/blob/81611b884328591b08111bdbe55fa7902760dc6b/src/app/api/prompt/route.ts) is the router.ts file I am referring to. The project is from [this YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/wm5gMKuwSYk?si=MjK7TpmbtX_IKJAs).

**UPD**
With the parameter in a path segment there is no issues during the build. So, at least there is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this error is thrown at the build time but in the development stage it works fine. In order to avoid "DynamicServerError" in the build phase, you need to add the following line in your "route.ts" file to change the behavior of the route handler to be fully dynamic like this:

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
```

For more information, go through the following [page](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config).